# adding autocomplete items to text box

Tags: jquery, input, autocomplete

I have 4 text boxes and I need to fill with auto complete. I have created the jsfiddle but not able to get it run as I am submitting to the server to get the data. When i click add button I am able to add to only first line of input boxes but never be able to add to others such as 2, 3 and 4. Could someone take a look? Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/qF5jU/2/

```
        $('[name=addAgent]').bind('click', function() {

            var agent = $('[name=selectAgent]').val();
            var agentID =$("#AgentID").val();
            //alert(agent);

            if(agent == ""){
            $.msgBox({
                title:"Agent Name",
                content:"Please search for an agent to Add!"
                });
            return false;
            }

            if($('#container').find('text').length < 4) {
            alert($('#container').find('text').length);             
           $('#Agent1').val(agent);
           $('#AgentID1').val(agentID);
            $( '[name=selectAgent]' ).val('');      
            }else{
                $.msgBox({
                title:"Agent Name",
                content:"You cannot add more than 4 Agents!"
                });
            }
        })
```

Comment: ex: John dow, 1234(Name and agent id two seperate input fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line gets the value for the 1st box with that name:

```
var agent = $('[name=selectAgent]').val();
```

If you want to get the value for the one clicked use this:

```
var agent = $(this).val();
```

Then, I'm not quite sure what the less than 4 part does but you need some code to decide where to put the new ones. These lines:

```
$('#Agent1').val(agent);
$('#AgentID1').val(agentID);
```

need to either be put into a loop of some sort, like this:

```
for (var i=1 ; i <= 4 ; ++i) {
    if (...something to decide if this is where you want it ...) {
        $('#Agent' + i).val(agent);
        $('#AgentID' + i).val(agentID);
    }
}
```

of some sort of group of 'if's, like this:

```
if (... 1 is it ...) {
    $('#Agent1').val(agent);
    $('#AgentID1').val(agentID);
} else if (... 2 is it ...) {
    $('#Agent2').val(agent);
    $('#AgentID2').val(agentID);
} else if (... 3 is it ...) {
    $('#Agent3').val(agent);
    $('#AgentID3').val(agentID);
} else  if (... 4 is it ...) {
    $('#Agent4').val(agent);
    $('#AgentID4').val(agentID);
}
```

Comment: Hi Lee, Sorry I a mnot clearly explained. I am able to get the value and ID for the selected click, I am adding it to pair of input boxes as "John Dow" "1234" . When I selct second item, "Brad Pitt" "5656" I need to write this to second pair of input boxes, instead it is overriting the first pair. I guess, I am trying to get handle of first click,second click and based on the counter or index copy the data to appropriate input pairs. Thanks!

Comment: How to get count of those 4 input boxes? If I can track of each click value then I can write itto appropriate input boxes.

Comment: Or add a hidden field for each of the four (either a true hidden field or something that's just not displayed) that you mark to show that one has been used. (Or just look for the 1st empty set of boxes.)

Comment: Is there anyway I can track each click ?

Comment: Sure. Just have a global variable that counts them. `var clickCount;` and then in the click function: `clickCount++;`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Lee. It is working perfect. I would like to add jQuery minusthik icon and add it next by each text box for giving delete text option. Do you think, I can also subtract from counter with "-" click?

```
var counter = 0;

$('[name=addAgent]').bind('click', function() {
            var agent = $('[name=selectAgent]').val();
            var agentID =$("#AgentID").val();
            //alert(agent);

            if(agent == ""){
                $.msgBox({
                    title:"Agent Name",
                    content:"Please search for an agent to Add!"
                    });
                return false;
            }


              alert(counter);   
                if(counter==1){
                    $('#Agent1').val(agent);
                    $('#AgentID1').val(agentID);                      

                }else if(counter==2){
                        $('#Agent2').val(agent);
                    $('#AgentID2').val(agentID);

                }else if(counter==3){
                        $('#Agent3').val(agent);
                    $('#AgentID3').val(agentID);

                }else if(counter==4){
                    $('#Agent4').val(agent);
                    $('#AgentID4').val(agentID);               

                }else{
                    $.msgBox({
                    title:"Agent Name",
                    content:"You cannot add more than 4 Agents!"
                    });
                }
                 $( '[name=selectAgent]' ).val('');


            counter++;

        });
```

Comment: Yep but when you have 3 and delete #2 and then add another, you either have to move #3 to #2 when #2 is deleted OR you have to let the next click figure out #2 is empty.